# How can I reduce Memory usage in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 9 and PHP 8, even if I have 0 queries in a certain page I get 25mb of memory usage, for the other pages that have queries it gets to 26mb for memory usage which is a lot for no data. The solutions I tried are the following:

1- AppServiceProvider
I added this **Model::preventLazyLoading(!app()->isProduction());**  and I got rid off all the n+1 functions.

2- I reduced Image sizes there are even pages without images and it has the same issue.

3- I use pagination to list data.

4- I only call the data I need.

Here are some solutions that I checked before posting:

[Reduce memory usage for database objects in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689847/reduce-memory-usage-for-database-objects-in-laravel)

[How to see memory usage in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684715/how-to-see-memory-usage-in-laravel)

https://omarbarbosa.com/posts/optimization-of-eloquent-queries-to-reduce-memory-usage

and some youtube videos which uses the exact same steps.

Nothing works I don't know what is the problem exactly. Any help would be appreciated I use Debugbar to check the memory usage and queries.

Comment: Have you tried run `php artisan optmize`?

Comment: Yes I did, It didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

There are many memory usage difference if you use Eloquent ORM.I'd suggest use raw queries with repository pattern maybe.